# Jest test process never completing after all tests pass. How can I get them to complete

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, jestjs

I have a Jest test class with 2 tests that are both passing fine. My problem is that when I run `yarn run test` my tests execute but Jest hangs. After digging around online I found a lot of people talking about not handling async/await correctly, but based on everything I see in the Jest docs my implementation is correct. I also tried running the tests with the flag --detectOpenHandles but it gives me no information. The last message I get in my console is "Ran all test suites." but it just hangs after that and never closes the test process. If I use the --forceExit flag is closes fine, but I don't want to have to use this. How can I get my tests to complete?

This is my test class:

```
describe('urlShortener middleware', () => {

  const LONG_URL = "www.google.com";
  const SHORT_URL = "www.g.com";

  let shortenUrl;

  const req = {
    body: {
      url: LONG_URL
    }
  };

  const res = { end: jest.fn(), json: jest.fn(), status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis() };

  const mockResponse = {
    body: {
      "short_url": SHORT_URL
    },
    status: 201  
  };

  let axiosMock = {
    post: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockResponse)
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    req.body = {url: LONG_URL};

    jest.setMock('axios', axiosMock);
    shortenUrl = require('../urlShortener').default;

    res.end.mockReset();
    res.json.mockReset();
    res.status.mockReset();

    res.status.mockReturnValue(res);
  });

  it('should return the data appropriately when nothing goes wrong', async (done) => {
    await shortenUrl(req, res);

    expect(axiosMock.post.mock.calls[0][1].original_url).toBe(LONG_URL);
    expect(res.status).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(res.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(201);
    expect(res.json).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ shortUrl: SHORT_URL });

    done();
  });

  it('should set the correct status when the world burns', async (done) => {
    axiosMock.post = jest.fn().mockRejectedValue(new Error());

    await shortenUrl(req, res);

    expect(res.status).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(res.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(500);
    expect(res.json).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

    done();
  });
});
```

Comment: *Where* are you seeing this? I had a similar problem when running in CircleCI that turned out to be due to Jest trying to spin up too many workers (detecting all cores on the VM, not just those available to the container); setting `--maxWorkers=2` solved that. Or are you just running it in watch mode; what *is* the `test` command? Note that you don't need to use `done` when you have `async` test functions; Jest can handle the promise for you: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm running it locally. My test command is just "jest". And yeah, I added the done when I was troubleshooting this issue.